# Multiple Kafka Streams with different topics ApplicationId

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Given a single component which can have multiple instances, and the following structure:

1. Stream1[Topic1, destination1]
2. Stream2[Topic2, destination2]

where destination is a *Queue* and all the links will be 1:1.

Do we need to set the same **applicationId** for each KafkaStream?
It is known that applicationId will generate client.id and group.id which are important for how the partitions are assigned.
Couldn't find anything in the official documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your program is different (ie, different `Topology`), you need to use different `application.id` config. Using the same `application.id` config requires that all instances execute the *exact* same `Topology`.

Of course, you could also build a single `Topology` that processed both topics at once:

```java
StreamsBuilder builder = ...

builder.stream("topic1")...to("destination1");
builder.stream("topic2")...to("destination2");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run two applications in the same JVM process with separate threads for starting both topologies, or you can simply run two independent JVM processes.  Both cases, use different ids.

Or you can run one process (one id), subscribe to both topics, but use `branch` operator to separate streams by topic names.

- https://www.confluent.io/blog/putting-events-in-their-place-with-dynamic-routing/
- https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#stateless-transformations